# How to limit execution time on a php script

Tags: php, linux, time, limit

I'm running a php script via Linux (not via my browser) (php script.php).
Now, I want to limit the execution time to let's say 10 seconds, which means that after 10 seconds the process will shutdown by itself. How can I do that?
Already tried set_time_limit.
Already tried sleep(10); exit();

None of them made the script to shutdown.

Comment: what version of php are you running? the set_time_limit is not working when safe_mode is on but safe_mode has been deprecated in 5.3 and removed in 5.4.
Try to use die() instead of exit()

Answer (score 1):

Change the maximum execution time (in seconds) in php.ini configuration file.

**max_execution_time = 7200**

search in php.ini

Comment: But I want the max execution time variable to be changed when running the script (php script.php 60) = running the script for 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `set_time_limit` function? You can check documentation [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

**function**

```
void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

Comment: As I said, already tried, looks like it didn't manage to terminate the process.